RStudio Knit object not found issue
I have called the rds file, it runs in the code, it is in the environment but when I try to knit the document, it says object not found.

I read the document, I called the document, the environment reads it


When kniting something, a fresh R session is started in the process. So it doesn't matter what's in your current environment, since a new different environment is used.

The current directory is used as the basis for code in the .rmd unless you use setwd(), but that's not your problem.

readRDS() (unlike load()) just reads the data, similar to read.csv(), you need assign the stuff to something.


fatalities <- readRDS('fatalities.rds')

